# Uniform continuity implies essential supremum be equal to supremum almost surely?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})= (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, $\mathbb{P}$ an arbitrary probability measure, and $\{X_i, i \in I\} \subset \mathbb{L}^0(\mathscr{F})$ where $I$ could possibly be uncountable. Assume $X_i$ is uniformly continuous in $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$, uniformly in $i$. Show that $esssup_{i \in I}^{\mathbb{P}}X_i = \sup_{i \in I}X_i$, $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.

1. I know the definition of uniform continuous function. But do not understand what this question means when saying: $X_i$ is uniformly continuous in $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$, uniformly in $i$.
2. Any suggestions how I may proceed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What is meant here is that for each given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that
   $$
   \forall i, \forall x,\forall y,\qquad |x-y|<\delta\Longrightarrow|X_i(x)-X_i(y)|<\epsilon.
   $$
2. Suggestions: (i) Show that $Y(x):=\sup_{i\in I}X_i(x)$ is a (uniformly) continuous function of $x$. In particular, $Y$ is $\mathcal B(\Bbb R))$ measurable; i.e a random variable.
   (ii) The random variable $Y$ has the properties required of an essential supremum, so it must be the essential supremum, so $Y= \,\,$esssup${}^{\Bbb P}_{i\in I}X_i$, $\Bbb P$-a.s.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now the question makes more sense. I could prove that $Y(x)$ is uniformly continuous. But, still don't know how it implies that $Y$ is Borel measurable. Is there any theorem in real analysis that implies this fact?

Comment: Because $Y$ is continuous, $Y^{-1}(G)$ is open  for each open set $G\subset \Bbb R$, hence $Y^{-1}(G)\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ for each open set $G$. The collection $\mathcal A:=\{B\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R):Y^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra contained in $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ and containing the class of open sets (which is a $\pi$-system generating $\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$). By the monotone class theorem, $\mathcal A=\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$. In other words, $Y^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal B(\Bbb R)$ for all $B\in \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$.